# Fastest c# Linq query for drop down

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, linq, drop-down-menu

I'm looking to perform the fastest possible drop down query that will poll a database via the internet returning json.  The code snippet is an c# MVC controller that gets called by a Jquery Ajax function.  I'm looking to find out if anyone has any ideas to improve performance.  There could be over 50,000 customer records.

Here is my MVC controller which is called every keypress that happens on the client.

```
//Load Customers as typing
public ActionResult DropDownLoader(string SearchText, int MaxResults)
{
    NovaDB db = new NovaDB((string)Session["DbConnection"]);

    var search1 = (from c in db.Customers
                   where c.Name.StartsWith(SearchText) || c.Street.StartsWith(SearchText) && c.Fresh == false
                   select new { XID = c.ID, Line1 = c.Name, Line2 = c.Street, Line3 = c.City + ", " + c.State + "  " + c.Zip, Search = 1 });
    var search2 = (from c in db.Customers
                    where c.Name.Contains(SearchText) || c.Street.Contains(SearchText) && c.Fresh == false
                   select new { XID = c.ID, Line1 = c.Name, Line2 = c.Street, Line3 = c.City + ", " + c.State + "  " + c.Zip, Search = 2 });

    var results = search1.Union(search2).OrderBy(x => x.Search).Take(MaxResults).ToList();

    return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Don't return 50,000 items at once .. anyway, what does the generated SQL look like? [How] is the SQL query slow? Is the data indexed as appropriate? It would probably be better to fold in the condition of the two queries (btw, Contains is a superset of StartsWith) .. but RDBMS are pretty darn smart.

Comment: No it doesn't return 50,000 at once, but it does start to search after the first 2 characters are entered.  I don't know how to find the generated SQL.  The app is still in development so no real world results yet, just looking to generate efficient code.  I want to give the StartsWith results before the Contains results, for better match results.  Thanks..

Comment: If using EF, see [Profiling Database Activity in the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx). (There might be newer/different methods, I only actively work with the L2S provider.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple different options

Cache the results for a given SearchText in the Controller so you don't have to query the database every time.

Don't start using the ajax function till the user has typed in a minimum # of characters.

Index the Customer.Name and Customer.Street columns on the database table

Evaluate the generated SQL to see if it can be improved.

Comment: Do you think it would be faster to use a cache and try to add or remove results from the cache based on the next search letter? 
I do wait for a minimum of characters (2).  I thought that indexes have lost favor in recent years?  I've heard that databases are smarter now and learn by your queries?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wouldn't worry so much about managing the cache. Use a cache policy which evicts items based on how long since they've been used. Indexes haven't lost favor, even in NoSQL databases.